# PHP slashes, quotes, etc. being removed in between variables

Tags: php, html, variables, echo

I'm not quite sure why this is happening. I took a gander at the PHP documentation but couldn't find what I was looking for, most likely due to less than adequate knowledge of the necessary terminology.

```
<?php echo $variable_x; ?>

<div style="background-image: url("photo.png"); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></div>

<?php echo $variable_y; ?>
```

On the pages I'm putting markup in between two PHP variables, it's breaking all the markup by removing quotes, slashes, etc. I don't know why. I looked around to see if there was some way to "end" the PHP statements since that's what I believed to be the cause.

Can anyone identify the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already surrounding with double quotes the style, change the quotes from background or remove them:

```
<div style="background-image: url(photo.png); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></div>
```

Adding them it will break your style, since the style ends with same type of quotes it started, the rest of the code breaks.

Or you can add a class and move CSS outside HTML in an external file.

Comment: You could do better than that by putting your css in an external file btw :)

Comment: It's actually a unique situation where I have to use the style attribute. I never use it, so I completely forgot about the quote confliction.

Answer (score 0):

In the style attribute of the div the url in the background image again has the double quotes.
Use this-

```
<div style="background-image: url('photo.png'); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;">
```

or this-

```
<div style='background-image: url("photo.png"); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

→ What happens when you do something like this:

```
<?php echo $variable_x; ?>

<?php echo '<div style="background-image: url(\'photo.png\'); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></div>'; ?>

<?php echo $variable_y; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style="background-image: url("photo.png"); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></div>
```

This is a parser killer. If you start with doublequotes make the inner string references single quoted or reverse... two corrected versions here:

```
 <div style="background-image: url('photo.png'); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></div>
```

or

```
 <div style='background-image: url("photo.png"); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;'></div>
```

Hope this helps...